# Why does a label permutation produce a different Huffman code?

Tags: python, algorithm, huffman-code

I'm generating Huffman codes based off the following input distributions:

```
a = [(1,0.5),(0,0.25),(0,0.125),(0,0.125)]
b = [(0,0.5),(1,0.25),(0,0.125),(0,0.125)]
```

Where the only difference is the 1 is in a different bin.

However when I encode these using the following function:

```
def encode(symbfreq):
    tree = [[wt, [sym, ""]] for sym, wt in symbfreq]
    heapq.heapify(tree)
    while len(tree)>1:
        lo, hi = heapq.heappop(tree), heapq.heappop(tree)
        for pair in lo[1:]:
            pair[1] = '0' + pair[1]
        for pair in hi[1:]:
            pair[1] = '1' + pair[1]
        heapq.heappush(tree, [lo[0] + hi[0]] + lo[1:] + hi[1:])
    return sorted(heapq.heappop(tree)[1:], key=lambda p: (len(p[-1]), p))
```

I get different codewords for the distribution:

```
a = [[1, '1'], [0, '00'], [0, '010'], [0, '011']]
```

whilst

```
b = [[0, '0'], [1, '11'], [0, '100'], [0, '101']]
```

Why am I getting this difference?

For reference: I'll need to split the tree into left and right branches (based on the left branch starting with a 1, the right a 0) as an attempt to find the 1. In the first case my algorithm should take 1 iterations and the second 2. However, because the codewords returned aren't the same for each bin each time both versions are currently taking 2 iterations to find the 1 - which isn't what I want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the fact that they looks different, this results are both right and *equivalent*.

You can make them look the same by sorting `lo` and `hi` branches so you always add `1` to the bigger branch by replacing:

```
lo, hi = heapq.heappop(tree), heapq.heappop(tree)
```

with:

```
lo, hi = sorted([heapq.heappop(tree), heapq.heappop(tree)], key=len)
```

Result

```
>>> encode(a)
3: [[1, '0'], [0, '10'], [0, '110'], [0, '111']]
>>> encode(b)
4: [[0, '0'], [1, '10'], [0, '110'], [0, '111']]
```